# WCF - Duplex channel - Will the callback method within request-reply operation come in thread pool thread?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-client

I am using dual channel with NetNamedPipeBinding. I am using callback methods to give progress to the client. I have couple questions. I am keen to confirm the behavior just to make sure my design doesn't have any flaws.

1. Will the callback method be invoked on thread pool thread? I looked at the debugger and it is coming from worker thread. Just want confirmation as I didnt see this detail in documentation.
2. Can I invoke a callback within request-reply operation?

   I tried this and its working. But is it recommended/ok to have a callback within request reply operation?

Please note that my service is running with persession instance mode and multiple concurrence mode to have effective throughput for my operations. And the operations are thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

About your question #2:

In my RPC framework design, i contains a CALLBACK-COMMAND in the response message.
that's just like you say "REQUEST-REPLY".